# XImage - how to resize?

Tags: image, resize, x11, rgb

I've got a XImage retrieved by XShmGetImage function. How can I resize it? Is there any function in X11 libraries to perform this operation or I need to use external library?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new one with the new size. An external library can't help because you would need the X server itself to cooperate.

Comment: OK, but I need a resized image. I don't need a blank image. Is there any way to resize an existing XImage?

Comment: If you mean change the pixel dimensions of the XImage, no, there is no way to do that.

If you want to *scale* the image pixels, you would use XRender on the server side or something like the Cairo library on the client side. But you still will have to scale *to* a different image (or window or pixmap), since you can't resize an allocated XImage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XRENDER](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/renderproto/plain/renderproto.txt) extension.